# File format for printing question

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, file-format

Novice here..I know very little about file types, and am so overwhelmed. 
I have an Ai file of a simple text logo that I need to send to a client where they will then insert it on their bills/invoices, etc..and print from their printer. My question is, what format should I send this to them in? The Jpg file I sent was too small. This seems like it should be so simple, but I cannot seem to grasp it:( Any help is so appreciated.

Comment: I usually send as a "eps" file but you can always make a zip folder contain various formats (AI,PDF,PNG)

Comment: I think you should keep eps out of the equation for now, both for the sake of Andrea and the client. Give them jpg or png.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with jpg, it is not the format that is wrong: if the one you gave them were "too small", you can scale up the logo in Illustrator or check your settings when you create the jpg.

Jpg and png are both perfectly good file formats, unless they ask for anything specific either should do fine.

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs! Yes, the client will be printing through Microsoft Office 16, so I would think a jpg would be appropriate. I'll attempt to scale up the logo or try the .png format. Thanks!!

Comment: Also, does it matter what size my artboard is? Right now it is set at 8.5x11...

Comment: The size of the logo matters. Your logo fills the artboard? And I am assuming 8.5x11 is not pixels or millimeters? inches, cm?

Answer (score 1):

The type of file they need is dependent on its usage. If the logo was generated in Illustrator, then your best bet is to export a .EPS file.

Most software will allow the importing of an EPS file. EPS is vector by nature, just like AI files, so it will print sharp regardless of how big or small - unless the software they use to import the file, rasterizes it.

Answer (score 0):

Am a Pre Press operator in a printing company. As per my view we always request our clients to provide a high resolution PDF file formats only.

The document must need bleed and final trim marks.

Comment: pdfs for putting on letterheads seems a little off.